# How to navigate to my app from calendar notification in android

Tags: android, calendar

Here is the code i used for adding an event in the calendar app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
        intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
        intent.putExtra("title", "Test Event");
        intent.putExtra("description", "This is a sample description");
        startActivity(intent);
```

I want to add the event in the calendar event page from my app and want to get back the notification from my app instead of calendar app. Please let me know, how can i do this.